# Invalid region error in MapKit

Tags: ios, ios7, mapkit

I am using MapKit, and every now and then I get the following error when starting the app.

```
'Invalid Region <center:nan, nan span:+180.00000000, +360.00000000>'
```

The code that I use for setting the region is the following.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    if (!self.initialLocation)
    {
        NSLog(@"Center is %f", userLocation.coordinate.longitude); // Debug
        [self calculateLocationAddress]; // Reverse geolocating, does not create the error
        self.initialLocation = userLocation.location;

        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center = userLocation.coordinate;

        // Region to show when app is loaded
        region.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.04, 0.04);

        region = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
        [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    }
}
```

The log in that method shows that the user location IS set, as I keep getting correct values in it, even though it crasches with the invalid region error. I have also tried using `CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid` to validate the region, same error though. As mentioned above, this error is very sporadical, showing up every now and then.
Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
The error pretty much always disappears if I open the storyboard and make a change to it before compiling again.

Comment: what i know is The problem is The latitude must be from -90 to +90 so +180.00000000, +360.00000000 is out of range.

Comment: Doing a test run shows that I get valid longitude and latitude, about +50 and +10.

Comment: Sometimes (coming from background to foreground, while prompting for location permission, etc), the map view calls this delegate method with a nil location or invalid location.  Try these two things at the top of the delegate method.  1) if userLocation.location is nil, exit the method (do nothing).  2) if CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(userLocation.coordinate) is NO, exit the method (do nothing).

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Anna, but the error occurs even when running the app after reinstalling it. I have also tried the two things you mentioned.

Comment: Why centre coordinates are NaN? Aren't those needed for a region? If you want to create a region from span and centre then you should do `MKCoordinateRegionMake(locationCentre, locationSpan)` whereas `locationCentre` and `locationSpan` are **CLLocationCoordinate2D** and **MKCoordinateSpan** respectively. Then you use the result from `RegionMake` in `[mapView regionThatFits:theResultFromMake]`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and it resolved from the below code.

```
if ( (region.center.latitude >= -90) && (region.center.latitude <= 90) && (region.center.longitude >= -180) && (region.center.longitude <= 180)) {
            self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            
            }
            else
            {
            print("Invalid region!")
        }
```

Happy Coding
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid instead

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/1423806-cllocationcoordinate2disvalid